# Sails:[TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined]

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo, sails.io.js

I'm trying to create google and facebook OpenId Authentication using passport.js.

When i trying to login via google and facebook but it showing [TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined]

please resolve this error.

Here i attached my model,controller and express.js files

Model User.js

```
userId      : {type: 'string'},
            loginName   : {type: 'string'},
            userName    : {type: 'string'},
            password    : {type: 'string'},
            userEmail   : {type: 'string'}
```

Usercontroller.js

```
 google: function(req, res) 
    {
     passport.authenticate('google', 
                            { 
                                failureRedirect: '/login', scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'] 
                            }, function(err, user) {
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.view('500');
          return;
        }

        res.redirect('/user/index');
        return;
      });
    })(req, res);
  },
  facebook: function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login', scope: ['email'] }, function(err, user) {
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.view('500');
          return;
        }

        res.redirect('/user/index');
        return;
      });
    })(req, res);
  }
```

express.js file

```
 var passport = require('passport')
    , FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
    , GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy

var verifyHandler = function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
  process.nextTick(function() {

    User.findOne({ userId : profile.id}, function(err, user) {
      if (user) 
      {
        return done(null, user);
      } 
      else 
      {
        var data = {
                        //provider: profile.provider,
                        userId : profile.id,
                        name: profile.displayName
                    };
        if (profile.emails && profile.emails[0] && profile.emails[0].value) 
        {
          data.email = profile.emails[0].value;
        }
        if (profile.name && profile.name.givenName)
        {
          data.firstname = profile.name.givenName;
        }
        if (profile.name && profile.name.familyName) 
        {
          data.lastname = profile.name.familyName;
        }
        User.create(data, function(err, user) 
        {
          return done(err, user);
        });
      }
    });
  });
};

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user. userId );
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(userId, done) {
  User.findOne({ userId :  userId }, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


module.exports.http = {

  customMiddleware: function(app) {

    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
      clientID: "1628965017378018",
      clientSecret: "85ad33be64ef80b4c53528d91c58713f",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:1337/user/facebook/callback"
    }, verifyHandler));

    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID: '775943647612-hpqptpku90s37d2m3114r8olm50ef0ar.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      clientSecret: 'JIqGkBqRqFGYd_zL6wzxJcko',
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:1337/user/google/callback'
    }, verifyHandler));


    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
  }
};
module.exports.cache = {
  maxAge: 31557600000
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't supposed to be a space after "user." in your code.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user. userId );
});
```